# Can't Flash Android THings on PICO-PI-IM6UL

Tags: android, flash, android-things

Can't flash Android Things on PICO-PI-IM6UL ,am using latest Developer Preview 6.
==>step i followed

1.Download image for PICO-PI
2.Un-Zipped 
3.clicked flash-all.bat (Am using Win10 Machine)

==>Output

`< waiting for any device >`

==> after that i used sb_loader to and tried to flash u-boot.imx

1. `.\sb_loader_imx6ul.exe -f .\u-boot.imx`

==> Output

```
Found USB#VID_15A2&PID_007D#6&7DC9D1B&0&2.
Reg 0x20c4068 is initialized.
Reg 0x20c406c is initialized.
Reg 0x20c4070 is initialized.
Reg 0x20c4074 is initialized.
Reg 0x20c4078 is initialized.
Reg 0x20c407c is initialized.
Reg 0x20c4080 is initialized.
Reg 0x20e04b4 is initialized.
Reg 0x20e04ac is initialized.
Reg 0x20e027c is initialized.
Reg 0x20e0250 is initialized.
Reg 0x20e024c is initialized.
Reg 0x20e0490 is initialized.
Reg 0x20e0288 is initialized.
Reg 0x20e0270 is initialized.
Reg 0x20e0260 is initialized.
Reg 0x20e0264 is initialized.
Reg 0x20e04a0 is initialized.
Reg 0x20e0494 is initialized.
Reg 0x20e0280 is initialized.
Reg 0x20e0284 is initialized.
Reg 0x20e04b0 is initialized.
Reg 0x20e0498 is initialized.
Reg 0x20e04a4 is initialized.
Reg 0x20e0244 is initialized.
Reg 0x20e0248 is initialized.
Reg 0x21b001c is initialized.
Reg 0x21b0800 is initialized.
Reg 0x21b080c is initialized.
Reg 0x21b083c is initialized.
Reg 0x21b0848 is initialized.
Reg 0x21b0850 is initialized.
Reg 0x21b081c is initialized.
Reg 0x21b0820 is initialized.
Reg 0x21b082c is initialized.
Reg 0x21b0830 is initialized.
Reg 0x21b08c0 is initialized.
Reg 0x21b08b8 is initialized.
Reg 0x21b0004 is initialized.
Reg 0x21b0008 is initialized.
Reg 0x21b000c is initialized.
Reg 0x21b0010 is initialized.
Reg 0x21b0014 is initialized.
Reg 0x21b0018 is initialized.
Reg 0x21b001c is initialized.
Reg 0x21b002c is initialized.
Reg 0x21b0030 is initialized.
Reg 0x21b0040 is initialized.
Reg 0x21b0000 is initialized.
Reg 0x21b001c is initialized.
Reg 0x21b001c is initialized.
Reg 0x21b001c is initialized.
Reg 0x21b001c is initialized.
Reg 0x21b001c is initialized.
Reg 0x21b0020 is initialized.
Reg 0x21b0818 is initialized.
Reg 0x21b0004 is initialized.
Reg 0x21b0404 is initialized.
Reg 0x21b001c is initialized.
DCD Write Success!

Executed plugin successfully.

 Loading Firmware.
Succeed to download .\u-boot.imx to the device.
Run into the image successfully.
```

after this i computer detect new hardware and i tried to update so got this

[Device manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQ0Hv.png)

=> after this i tried to flash

```
PS C:\Users\Faris\Downloads\PicoPi-MXUL_NXP Pico i.MX6UL_1_userdebug_build> .\flash-all.bat
target reported max download size of 419430400 bytes
sending 'bootloader' (491 KB)...
OKAY [  0.016s]
writing 'bootloader'...
FAILED (remote:  device is locked.)
finished. total time: 0.047s
```

Note :- I installed Android Studio and ADB drivers

Answer (score 1):

Unlock the bootloader with 'fastboot flashing unlock' then try again

Comment: Thanks , just solved my problem , but when i try to flash `PS C:\Users\Faris\Downloads\PicoPi-MXUL_NXP Pico i.MX6UL_1_userdebug_build> .\flash-all.bat
target reported max download size of 419430400 bytes
sending 'bootloader' (491 KB)...
OKAY [  0.016s]
writing 'bootloader'...
OKAY [  0.266s]
rebooting into bootloader...
OKAY [  0.000s]
finished. total time: 0.281s
< waiting for any device >
`

Comment: > fastboot oem unlock
...
OKAY [  0.016s]
finished. total time: 0.016s

but is stuck when i try 

 .\flash-all.bat
target reported max download size of 419430400 bytes
sending 'bootloader' (491 KB)...
OKAY [  0.031s]
writing 'bootloader'...
OKAY [  0.250s]
rebooting into bootloader...
OKAY [ -0.000s]
finished. total time: 0.281s
< waiting for any device >

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with the UBoot boot loader, you need to make a clean test on your device.

I had a similar issue with PICO-PI IMX6UL boards, i made an error flashing IMX7D image on IMX6UL...so

I studied resources of IMX6UL.

To make a clean test, you need to reflash the bootloader first, (u-boot android compatible version) using mgftools, than you can flash your image with flash-all of your android things image.

Try to follow this step by step:

- Download the mfgtool from here: http://www.nxp.com/lgfiles/bsps/mfgtools.zip
- Move jumpers of the board like described at 4.1.3 (first picture)
  https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/PICO-IMX6UL-USG.pdf
- Follow the instruction at 9.1 but using this vbs name
  mfgtool2-brillo-mx6ul-pico-emmc-firmware.vbs
  https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/quick-reference-guide/PICO-iMX7D-QSG.pdf
- Wait treeminutes
- If success with DONE 100%/100%.
- Revert jumpers of the board like described at 4.1.3 (second picture
  on the other page)
  https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/PICO-IMX6UL-USG.pdf
- Reboot the board (unplug usb-c)

At this point the board must be in fastboot
So you can see it using "fastboot devices"

Comment: [error](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/qvIUJgQ_GC7Z5mqQsWvRBu4Kbq1oRmjtekyglkcssnqNCNtGbSlenB24HBpDRckBUrHcckURxA=w260-h113-n-rw)

Comment: so is 100% hardware issue